# Spring Boot Kotlin 1.7.20 K2 Compiler Spring Plugin doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I was trying to use the Kotlin K2 compiler with my Spring Boot application.

Unfortunately it seems like the Spring Kotlin plugin isn't supported yet or I am doing something wrong with my configuration.

As the [official blog-post states](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1720.html#support-for-kotlin-k2-compiler-plugins), the `all-open` & `no-arg` plugin is supported. Although the Kotlin plugin seems not to be supported yet even if it includes both of these plugins?

When I start up my application with the following settings enabled in my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.14.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.20"
}
```

and K2 compiler enabled via `"-Xuse-k2"` option:

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xuse-k2")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```

The application fails to start up with the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Configuration class 'MyConfigurationClass' may not be final. Remove the final modifier to continue.
Offending resource: class path resource [com/my/path/MyConfigurationClass.class]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClass.validate(ConfigurationClass.java:217) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.validate(ConfigurationClassParser.java:215) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation ..
```

which tells me that the `all-open` plugin doesn't seem to work anymore.

Has anyone managed to use the K2 compiler plugin for their Kotlin based Spring Boot application and can help me?

Comment: Seems to be, that the k2 compiler is not supporting transitive meta-annotations. There is an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53590/K2-Allopen-does-not-look-for-transitive-meta-annotations

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that the K2 compiler have a bug with transitive meta-annotations: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53590/K2-Allopen-does-not-look-for-transitive-meta-annotations

Workaround for me was to manually add the annotations we are using within our spring service in the build.gradle(.kts):

```
allOpen {
    annotation("org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration")
    annotation("org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication")
}
```

Please note, that the k2 compiler is still in alpha status. So hopefully this will be fixed in the near future.